# Name of the point whose coordinates are the mean of the coordinates of a list of points.

Tags: geometry, terminology

Let $ X = \{ (x_i,y_i) \, | \, i \in I\}$
be a set of points (where $I$ is a finite index set).

Does the point $x_0 = \frac{1}{|I|} \sum_{i \in I} (x_i,y_i) $ have any name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the barycenter of the sets of points.

Answer (score 12):

In geometry it's called [*centroid*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid), *geometric center* or *barycenter*.

Please note that depending on context, the latter term may be ambiguous because in physics *barycenter* has a slightly different meaning: [the center of mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass) (which may or may not be the same as the centroid, depending on the distribution of mass).

Answer (score 1):

It can be called the first moment of the set of points.  This notion of 'moments' generalizes a lot.  For example, suppose that the points have an associated "weight" $w_i$.  Then,

$$p = \sum_i w_i \cdot (x_i, y_i)$$

is the first moment with respect to $w_i$.  In your case, $w_i$ is constantly $\frac{1}{|I|}$.

Comment: I think you mean "first moment" or "first raw moment", rather than "first central moment". The first *central* moment is zero.